# Splitting line GeoDataFrame basing on given lengths

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, splitting

I am trying to split line GeoDataFrame into sections. I have lengths on which splits should be made stored in column. My idea was to generate points along the line using `shapely.ops.interpolate` and then split lines with `shapely.ops.split` and collect all the results in new GeoDataFrame.
Unfortunatelly, `shapely.ops.split` returns given line as if generated points would not intersect with it.
Here is my code:

```
lines = []
for split_distances, line in zip(suln1234['split_distances'], suln1234['geometry']):
    points = []
    if split_distances:
        for split_distance in split_distances:
            points.append(line.interpolate(split_distance))
        splitted = shapely.ops.split(line, shapely.ops.snap(shapely.geometry.MultiPoint(points), line, 1))
        for i in splitted:
            lines.append(i)
    else:
        lines.append(line)

l_split = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': lines}, crs=suln1234.crs)
```

As you can see, I also tried to use `shapely.ops.snap`, but even with crazy big tolerance, it only works for part of lines.
What is the reason for such behaviour? I would imagine that if points are derived directly from line, they should allign nicely with its geometry. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, due to floating point issues, a point being on the linestring (due to `nearest_points` or `interpolate`) does not always result in the point intersecting with the linestring. There are [several issues](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/1058#issuecomment-755016543) in the shapely repository discussing this exact pain point. The answer is just better documentation.

In order to guarantee that a point will split a line, you need to snap the *Linestring* to the *Point* (or *MultiPoint*), not the other way around.

```
from shapely.ops import split, snap

def split_line_by_point(line, point, tolerance: float=1.0e-12):
    return split(snap(line, point, tolerance), point)
```

The reason it works this way and not the other is that snapping a *LineString* to a *Point* inserts the point as a vertex of the linestring itself and the two geometries then reliably intersect. <del>Snapping a *Point* to a *LineString* only places the point somewhere on the line, which is still subject to precision issues when interpolating between two vertices to test if the point is on the line.</del> Having second thoughts. [Snapping](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.snap) a *Point* to a *LineString* should snap the point to a vertex of the line, not just anywhere as I was thinking. But if a vertex is not nearby (in your case, within 1) even if the point is on the line it will not be placed on a vertex. Maybe that is what is going on in your case? Could the vertices of your line be more than 1 apart? Either way it seems preferable to snap the *LineString* to the *Point* not the *Point* to the *LineString*.

Comment: Switching the snapping direction helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is not the common way to iterate over rows in a (Geo)DataFrame, see [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas), [Different ways to iterate over rows in Pandas Dataframe](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-iterate-over-rows-in-pandas-dataframe/) and many more.

As you and Jeremiah England I use the snap option to split the lines ([Shapely issue: Floating point issue with splitter points](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/1058) )

```
import geopandas as gpd
lines = gpd.read_file("lines.shp")
print(lines)
    dist           geometry
0    10  LINESTRING (1.00000 2.00000, 8.00000 7.00000, ...
1    15  LINESTRING (2.09821 15.04000, 0.12726 10.25341...
```

[image]

With [Pandas itertuples()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) for example

```
from shapely.ops import snap, split
for i, row in enumerate(lines.itertuples()):
    splited = split(snap(row.geometry,row.geometry.interpolate(row.dist),0.01),row.geometry.interpolate(row.dist))
    for geom in splited:
        print(i, geom.wkt)
0 LINESTRING (1 2, 8 7, 6.749881714669379 6.374940857334689)
0 LINESTRING (6.749881714669379 6.374940857334689, 4 5, 2 4, 4 7, 8 5, 9 18, 1 2, 12 7, 4 5, 6 5, 4 9)
1 LINESTRING (2.098212290502795 15.04, 0.1272625698324044 10.25340782122905, 9.682839377571781 7.974770274768124)
1 LINESTRING (9.682839377571781 7.974770274768124, 9.888156424581005 7.925810055865924, 9.625363128491619 3.420782122905029, 13.43586592178771 3.664804469273745)

segs = []
distances = []
for row in lines.itertuples():
    splited = split(snap(row.geometry,row.geometry.interpolate(row.dist),0.01),row.geometry.interpolate(row.dist))
    for geom in splited:
      segs.append(geom)
      distance.append(row.dist)

l_split = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'dist':distance,'geometry': segs})
print(l_split)     
    dist                  geometry
0    10  LINESTRING (1.00000 2.00000, 8.00000 7.00000, ...
1    10  LINESTRING (6.74988 6.37494, 4.00000 5.00000, ...
2    15  LINESTRING (2.09821 15.04000, 0.12726 10.25341...
3    15  LINESTRING (9.68284 7.97477, 9.88816 7.92581, ...
```

or directly

```
cols = ['dist','geometry']
l_split = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns=cols)
for row in tt.itertuples():
   splited = split(snap(row.geometry,row.geometry.interpolate(row.dist),0.01),row.geometry.interpolate(row.dist))
for geom in splited:
    l_split = l_split.append({'dist': row.dist,'geometry':j },ignore_index=True)
print(l_split)     
    dist                  geometry
0    10  LINESTRING (1.00000 2.00000, 8.00000 7.00000, ...
1    10  LINESTRING (6.74988 6.37494, 4.00000 5.00000, ...
2    15  LINESTRING (2.09821 15.04000, 0.12726 10.25341...
3    15  LINESTRING (9.68284 7.97477, 9.88816 7.92581, ...
```

[image]

### New

```
for dist, geom in zip(tt.dist, tt.geometry):
    splited = split(snap(geom,geom.interpolate(dist),0.01),geom.interpolate(dist))
    for i in splited:
        print(i.wkt)
LINESTRING (1 2, 8 7, 6.749881714669379 6.374940857334689)
LINESTRING (6.749881714669379 6.374940857334689, 4 5, 2 4, 4 7, 8 5, 9 18, 1 2, 12 7, 4 5, 6 5, 4 9)
LINESTRING (2.098212290502795 15.04, 0.1272625698324044 10.25340782122905, 9.682839377571781 7.974770274768124)
LINESTRING (9.682839377571781 7.974770274768124, 9.888156424581005 7.925810055865924, 9.625363128491619 3.420782122905029, 13.43586592178771 3.664804469273745)
```

And with list comprehension;

```
segs = [split(snap(geom,geom.interpolate(dist),0.01),geom.interpolate(dist)) for dist, geom in zip(tt.dist, tt.geometry)]
```

Comment: Are you sure about iterating with for-loops? I based my approach on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/3553707 from one of the topics you linked, but perhaps I misunderstood something.

Comment: It is an only an opinion.

Comment: Look above in New for  a solution like yours