# Shapely split() function return the line to split

Tags: python, shapely

Probably the problem is related to floating point, but I need to find a solution and I'm running out of ideas.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from shapely.ops import nearest_points

line = wkt.loads('LINESTRING (438260.8093535866 4528121.6968436185, 441547.1377254081 4524732.670710177)')
print(line.length)
point = wkt.loads('POINT (441547.1377254081 4526413.179536677)')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
ax.set_xlabel('X coordinate', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Y coordinate', fontsize=15)

ax.scatter(
    *point.xy,
    label='Point',
    s=100,
    facecolor='orange',
    edgecolor='black'
)
plt.plot(*line.xy, label='LineString')

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

My line is long 4720.747006628025 km
[image]

So, I find the closest point:

```
minimum_distance = nearest_points(point, line)[1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
ax.set_xlabel('X coordinate', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Y coordinate', fontsize=15)

ax.scatter(
    *minimum_distance.xy,
    label='Minimum distance point',
    s=100,
    facecolor='red',
    edgecolor='black'
)

ax.scatter(
    *point.xy,
    label='Point',
    s=100,
    facecolor='orange',
    edgecolor='black'
)

plt.plot(*line.xy, label='LineString')

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Perfect!

Now I can split my line:

```
split_line = split(line, minimum_distance)

for l in list(split_line):
    print(l.length)
```

The result is only one line with the same length of my input line.
Probably for some cent of nanometer the closest point isn't on the input line, so I try to snap the point to the input line:

```
snap_point = snap(minimum_distance, line, 1e-8)

assert minimum_distance.wkt == snap_point.wkt
assert line.distance(minimum_distance) < 1e-8
```

The output is the same of `minimum_distance` and the output is already on the line because I haven't errors.

Can you suggest to me a workaround?
I need to split the line and now I haven't a solution to this simple problem.

*Note*: the EPSG is 32633

*Note2*: I opened an [issue](https://github.com/shapely/shapely/issues/1365) on shapely's github repository

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I need to split a line. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a well-known problem due to floating point issues and there are several issues in the shapely repository, look at the answer of Jeremiah England in [Splitting line GeoDataFrame basing on given lengths](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/386527/2581) for the details ([Floating point issue with splitter point](https://github.com/shapely/shapely/issues/1058#issuecomment-755016543), [ENH: split lines with point layer](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1356#issuecomment-609853005))

**Solution 1**: in order to guarantee that a point will split a line, you need to [snap](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.snap) the Linestring to the Point (with a tolerance).

Snapping a line to a point inserts the point as a vertex of the line itself, which is not the case with snapping a point to a line as in your solution.

```
minimum_distance = nearest_points(point, line)[1]
res = split(snap(line, minimum_distance, 0.0001), minimum_distance)
for lin in res:
   print(lin)
LINESTRING (438260.8093535866 4528121.696843619, 440707.280971606 4525598.772987535)
LINESTRING (440707.280971606 4525598.772987535, 441547.1377254081 4524732.670710177)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
ax.plot(*point.xy,'or')
ax.plot(*snap(line, minimum_distance, 0.0001).xy,'ob')
for lin in res:
    ax.plot(*lin.xy)
```

[image]

**Solution 2**: buffer based ([Shapely unable to split line on point due to precision issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50194810/835653))

```
buffer = minimum_distance.buffer(0.0001)
### Split the line on the buffer
first_seg, buff_seg, last_seg = split(line,buffer)
### Stitch together the first segment, the interpolated point, and the last segment 
line= LineString(list(first_seg.coords) + list(minimum_distance.coords) + list(last_seg.coords))
res = split(line,minimum_distance)
for lin in res:
    print(lin)
LINESTRING (438260.8093535866 4528121.696843619, 440707.280902036 4525598.77305928, 440707.280971606 4525598.772987535)
LINESTRING (440707.280971606 4525598.772987535, 440707.2810411764 4525598.772915791, 441547.1377254081 4524732.670710177)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
ax.plot(*point.xy,'or')
ax.plot(*snap(line, minimum_distance, 0.0001).xy,'ob')
for lin in res:
   ax.plot(*lin.xy)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @gene I hope that soon will be possible to split line with an not tortuos way

Comment: For the moment Shapely and GEOS cannot reduce precision floating-point precision problems.