# Interpolated Point on Line is not actually on Line?

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I am trying to debug a problem and am not sure if it is my code or if there's a bug with shapely.

I have two geodataframes: one with points and one with lines. For each point in the points geodataframe, I am trying to find the closest line to this point, and then get the closest projected point interpolated along the closest line.

In other words, give me the closest point on the closest line to my point, but not necessarily an existing vertex on the line.

```
points = #.. geodataframe of Points
lines = #.. geodataframe of LineStrings

nearest_points = []

for point in points['geometry']:
    nearest_line = lines.loc[lines.distance(point).idxmin()]['geometry']
    nearest_point = nearest_line.interpolate(nearest_line.project(point))
    nearest_points.append(nearest_point)
    
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': nearest_points}, crs=points.crs)
```

I would imagine that taking the intersection of the resulting closest point geodataframe against the lines geodataframe would yield the closest points created in the previous step since they are supposed to be points interpolated along the closest line.

However:

```
len(geopandas.overlay(gdf, lines, how='intersection', keep_geom_type = False))
```

does NOT EQUAL:

```
len(lines)
```

When I inspect the data in QGIS, I can see that the points do not fall exactly on the lines.

Is this a shapely bug?

**UPDATE**:

Here's a picture. Basically, the little orange points should lie exactly on the line since, but they are offset by a tiny fraction of an amount.

[image]

What I am trying to do is add nodes to a network of lines so the points have to be exactly on the line. The next step will be to split the lines at the points, but I cannot progress with the points as they are and snapping won't work because shapely snaps to the nearest vertex.

**UPDATE 2:**

@BERA's solution seems like it should have worked, but intersecting the resulting lines with the original lines should have picked up all the end points and did not.

I wrote something that does work, but it required snapping the closest line to the nearest point on that line and updating the line's geometry to actually work.

Finally, I tried comparing the nearest_point and spatial join solution output geometries with the geometries of the output from the snapped solution and there seem to be unequal geometries, but when they are printed, they look identical. I'm pretty stumped.

```
def create_connecting_lines(pointsdf, linesdf):
    connection_lines = []

    def _nearest_line(point, lines):
        return lines.loc[lines.geometry.distance(point).idxmin()]

    def _segments(curve):
        segs = list(map(LineString, zip(curve.coords[:-1], curve.coords[1:])))
        return geopandas.GeoDataFrame(segs, columns=["geometry"], crs=linesdf.crs)

    def _nearest_point(point, line):
        return line.interpolate(line.project(point))

    def _snap_line_to_point(line, point):
        return snap(line, point, 0.0001)

    for index, point in pointsdf.iterrows():
        # get the closest line
        line = _nearest_line(point.geometry, linesdf)

        if len(line.geometry.coords) > 2:
            # split into individual segments
            segs = _segments(line.geometry)
            # get the nearest segment
            _line = _nearest_line(point.geometry, segs)
            # get the nearest point on segment
            nearest_point = _nearest_point(point.geometry, _line.geometry)
            # snap the line to the point
            _line = _snap_line_to_point(line.geometry, nearest_point)
            # reset the line geometry to the snapped geometry
            linesdf.at[line.name, "geometry"] = _line
            # create connecting line
            connection_line = LineString([point.geometry, nearest_point])
            connection_lines.append(connection_line)
        else:
            nearest_point = _nearest_point(point.geometry, line.geometry)
            # snap the line to the point
            _line = _snap_line_to_point(line.geometry, nearest_point)
            # reset the line geometry to the snapped geometry
            linesdf.at[line.name, "geometry"] = _line
            # create connecting line
            connection_line = LineString([point.geometry, nearest_point])
            connection_lines.append(connection_line)

    the_lines = gpd.GeoDataFrame({"geometry": connection_lines}, crs=linesdf.crs)
    the_lines["length"] = the_lines.geometry.length

    return the_lines
```

**SOLUTION 1: nearest_points**

```
linedf["linegeom"] = linedf.geometry
sj = gpd.sjoin_nearest(pointdf, linedf[["linegeom", "geometry"]], how="left")
sj["nearest_points"] = sj.apply(lambda row: nearest_points(g1=row["geometry"], g2=row["linegeom"]), axis=1)
sj["shortest_line"] = sj.apply(lambda row: LineString(row["nearest_points"]), axis=1)
sj = sj.set_geometry("shortest_line").set_crs(linedf.crs).drop(columns="geometry").rename_geometry("geometry")
```

**SOLUTION 2: snapping**

```
the_lines = create_connecting_lines(pointdf, linedf)
```

**COMPARISON:**

```
print(all(the_lines.geometry == sj.geometry)) # false
print(len(pointdf)) # 757
print(len(sj) == len(pointdf)) # true
print(len(gpd.overlay(the_lines, linedf, 'intersection', keep_geom_type=False))) # there are 757 intersecting points - this is correct
print(len(gpd.overlay(sj, linedf, 'intersection', keep_geom_type=False))) # there are 747 intersecting points, not correct

# get the index where geometries don't match
idx = the_lines.loc[the_lines.geometry != sj.geometry].index


print(the_lines.loc[the_lines.geometry != sj.geometry][:1].geometry.values)

<GeometryArray>
[<LINESTRING (3043280.994 1619771.3, 3043307.474 1619792.514)>]
Length: 1, dtype: geometry

print(sj.loc[idx][:1].geometry.values)

<GeometryArray>
[<LINESTRING (3043280.994 1619771.3, 3043307.474 1619792.514)>]
Length: 1, dtype: geometry
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the shapely function nearest_points https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311616/find-coordinate-of-the-closest-point-on-polygon-in-shapely?

Comment: can you please add a picture to show us what is going on

Comment: @user30184 I will try it. If it works, I'll update the question, but I would still like to know why the interpolate/project method does not seem to work. I can only guess that it may be interpolating y=mx+b from line end points so if there's a curved line it misses point placement.

Comment: This https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/465954/qgis-firenze-splitting-line-at-points-not-working seems to deal with the same problem, though not in Python.

Comment: Look at  answer in  [Shapely split() function return the line to split](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/428955/shapely-split-function-return-the-line-to-split/t)

Comment: @gene thanks. looks like a floating point issue in shapely.

Comment: It is a GEOS problem, see [How to deal with rounding errors in Shapely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28036167/835653)

Comment: @gene very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I would use `sjoin_nearest` and `nearest_points`

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import nearest_points
from shapely.geometry import LineString

linedf = gpd.read_file(r"C:\GIS\GIStest\nearest_point\road.shp")
pointdf = gpd.read_file(r"C:\GIS\GIStest\nearest_point\points.shp")

#Join lines to points. That way you dont need to measure the distances from each point to all lines.
linedf["linegeom"] = linedf.geometry #Save line geometry or it is lost in the spatial join. 
# You might want to set a max_distance if you have big data frames.
sj = gpd.sjoin_nearest(pointdf, linedf[["linegeom", "geometry"]], how="left")

sj["nearest_points"] = sj.apply(lambda row: nearest_points(g1=row["geometry"], g2=row["linegeom"]), axis=1)

#The column contains the nearest point on the point geometry (the point itself), and the nearest
#  point on the line geometry
#sj.iloc[0].nearest_points
#Out[9]: (<POINT (317550.408 6519270.929)>, <POINT (317571.541 6519258.461)>)

#Create a line between them
sj["shortest_line"] = sj.apply(lambda row: LineString(row["nearest_points"]), axis=1)
sj = sj.set_geometry("shortest_line").set_crs(linedf.crs).drop(columns="geometry").rename_geometry("geometry")

ax = linedf.plot(color="grey", linewidth=1, figsize=(10,15))
sj.plot(ax=ax, linewidth=1, color="red")
pointdf.plot(ax=ax, markersize=10, color="blue")
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution was good, but when I tried intersecting sj with linedf to check that every endpoint was connected to a line, it ended up missing some points. I'll update my question with this new info. It seems like a strange bug.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked. It required snapping the closest lines to the closest interpolated point on that line which is odd and potentially undesirable. Shapely nearest_points did not work. See the updated question for additional information.

```
def create_connecting_lines(pointsdf, linesdf):
    connection_lines = []

    def _nearest_line(point, lines):
        return lines.loc[lines.geometry.distance(point).idxmin()]

    def _segments(curve):
        segs = list(map(LineString, zip(curve.coords[:-1], curve.coords[1:])))
        return geopandas.GeoDataFrame(segs, columns=["geometry"], crs=linesdf.crs)

    def _nearest_point(point, line):
        return line.interpolate(line.project(point))

    def _snap_line_to_point(line, point):
        return snap(line, point, 0.0001)

    for index, point in pointsdf.iterrows():
        # get the closest line
        line = _nearest_line(point.geometry, linesdf)

        if len(line.geometry.coords) > 2:
            # split into individual segments
            segs = _segments(line.geometry)
            # get the nearest segment
            _line = _nearest_line(point.geometry, segs)
            # get the nearest point on segment
            nearest_point = _nearest_point(point.geometry, _line.geometry)
            # snap the line to the point
            _line = _snap_line_to_point(line.geometry, nearest_point)
            # reset the line geometry to the snapped geometry
            linesdf.at[line.name, "geometry"] = _line
            # create connecting line
            connection_line = LineString([point.geometry, nearest_point])
            connection_lines.append(connection_line)
        else:
            nearest_point = _nearest_point(point.geometry, line.geometry)
            # snap the line to the point
            _line = _snap_line_to_point(line.geometry, nearest_point)
            # reset the line geometry to the snapped geometry
            linesdf.at[line.name, "geometry"] = _line
            # create connecting line
            connection_line = LineString([point.geometry, nearest_point])
            connection_lines.append(connection_line)

    the_lines = gpd.GeoDataFrame({"geometry": connection_lines}, crs=linesdf.crs)
    the_lines["length"] = the_lines.geometry.length

    return the_lines
```